# Can you replace an abstract class with AspectJ

Tags: java, abstract-class, aspectj

Given `java.util.Timer` you can do something like:

```
// where TimerMock extends Timer
Timer around(): call (Timer.new()) {
    return new TimerMock();
}
```

Is this possible to do with abstract classes? Take for example `java.util.TimerTask` which is an `abstract` class with the following signature:

```
public abstract class TimerTask implements Runnable {
    (...)
    public abstract void run();
}
```

**Would it be possible to return a class that extends TimerTask?**

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a hard time matching the join points correctly.

Let me use your initial example to explain the problems :

```
public aspect InterceptTimer
{
    // where TimerMock extends Timer
    Timer around(): call(Timer.new())
    {
         return new TimerMock();
    }
}

public class Test {

    public void method() 
    {
        Timer a = new Timer();
        System.out.println(a.toString());
    }
}
```

After the weaving AspectJ will replace `Timer a = new Timer();` for something semantically equivalent to  `Timer a = new TimerMock();` which works fine.

However, with the abstract class, things are not so smooth. In this case, you want to replace the concrete implementations of the abstract class by your concrete class. An aspect to do that could be something like (assuming now that TimerMock extends TimerTask) :

```
public aspect InterceptTimer
{
    // where TimerMock extends Timer
    TimerTask around(): call(TimerTask+.new()) && !within(InterceptTimer)
    {
        return new TimerMock();
    }  
}
```

The `"TimerTask+"` makes sure you intercept all classes that extend `TimerTask` and `"!within(InterceptTimer)"` makes sure that the pointcut does not intercept the join point `"new TimerMock();"` which would lead to infinite recursion.

Now let's assume that you have a concrete class such that:

```
public class MyTimer extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to intercept the following creation:

```
public void method() {
    MyTimer a = new MyTimer();
    a.run();
}
```

You get immediately the error:
"
incompatible return type applying to constructor-call(void 
 test.MyTimer.())
"

that is because the join point "new MyTimer()" is lexically different than "TimerTask". If you could change the "new MyTimer()" join point by "new TimerTask()" it would work, however, you cannot do that since TimerTask is an abstract class.

If you try to be clever and change the "advice" to: `Object around(): call(MyTask+.new()) && !within(InterceptTimer){...}`

you will not get a compile error but instead a runtime error:

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: test.TimerMock cannot be cast to test.MyTimer"
```

that is because during the weaving AspectJ will do the following: `MyTimer a = (MyTimer) new TimerMock();`

I do not think is possible to do what you want, at least not with that approach, maybe there is a way of doing it by exploiting the differences between "execution" and "call" join points.

Comment: Thks for the level of detail!